# Access arraylist which way is better

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

As I have there are 4 ways to access an arraylist.

1) Looping using Java5 foreach loop.
2) Looping ArrayList using for loop and size() method.
3) Iterating ArrayList using Iterator.
4) Traversing ArrayList using ListIterator in Java.

My question is..are all the same? All are good? any difference? (especially for Iterator I ask it)

Comment: Have you looked at the bytecode generated from the compiler? That's what I'd do to compare the above. The results may surprise you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because there is no single right answer. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) in the help for details.

Comment: IMHO option 2 is best for "arrayList". For linkedlist however I would choose 1. But the difference is performance is too negligible in most of the worldly usecases so I wouldn't worry much about the technique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) preferable in case you do not need to track the index / position of the items, you won't delete items in mid of iteration. This strategy removes the burden of explicitly fetching the next item to process.

2) preferable when you need to track the index / position of the item you do process. You are still able to modify the list but have to fetch the items to process by yourself.

3) preferable if you like to remove items from the list while iterating. you do not need to manage indexes / position of your own compared to 2)

4) preferable if you need to traverse the list forward and backward, replace items etc. while iterating

Each of them have their use cases.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your java version in my opinion!

If you are using Java 8, I recommend streams. Otherwise it also depends on what you need to do with the data:

```
for (Object o : yourArrayList) {...}
```

This is more efficient than using something such as `for (int i = 0; i < yourList.size(); i++) {...}` for iteration, because you don't have to traverse the entire list to get every object (not sure if the list does any internal caching or not). If you need to remove objects, use either an `Iterator` or Java 8's streams:

```
Iterator<Object> itr = yourArrayList.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    Object o = itr.next();
    //conditional around o, assume it's true for this example and remove 'o'
    itr.remove();
}
```

The only time I would recommend using the vanilla for-loop would be for tracking position of items.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the use

**Ex**

```
List<String> x=new ArrayList();
```

traversing using for-each and iterator is very much similar because for-each loop implements an implicit iterator.

```
for(String a:x){

}
```

But if you want to access elements according to it's position then use normal for loop

```
for(int i=0;i<x.size();i++){
    x.get(i);//access each elements according to pos.
}
```